# What will happen to Read or Write requests In case of Invalid Connections in Connection pool

Tags: mysql, connection, connection-pooling

If any of the Mysql cluster nodes go down or master migration happens then some of the connections in the pool will be invalid. In that case, if the Query comes before the connection TTL expiry then is Mysql client return the error or it will validate the connection every time and if it is is invalid then it will try to create the new connection and return the response.

Answer (score 0):

It will hold the request in the queue and the Cluster Manager will restart failed nodes and move the request from the queue to the node.